# android multi table adapters queries

Tags: android, sqlite, adapter, multi-table

I've been reading about having multiples tables in a SQLite database in Android. 
One approach is to have 1 adapter class for each table, and each adapter will implement CRUDs methods for each table.

My questions are:

1. Is this the best aproach to handling differents tables in one SQLite database?.
2. In this case, how can I execute sql queries between tables?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make various instances of SQLiteHelper `sqLiteHelper1`, `sqLiteHelper2`;

```
sqLiteHelper1 =  SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME1, null,MYDATABASE_VERSION);
sqLiteHelper2 =  SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME2, null,MYDATABASE_VERSION);
sqLiteDatabase1 = sqLiteHelper1.getWritableDatabase();
sqLiteDatabase2 = sqLiteHelper2.getWritableDatabase();
```

using `sqLiteDatabase1`, `sqLiteDatabase2`, access the data of different tables..

I hope this works :)